# Entity Framework Attach() after Include() performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

After [eagerly loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) an entity and reattaching it in a separate context, I am experiencing very serious performance problems.

Example below.  Employees are eagerly loaded when the company is first fetched.  There are 1000s of employees.

It then takes a few seconds to attach the Company in a second context.

```
Company company;

using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    company = context
        .Companies
        .Include(x => x.Employees)
        .Single(x => x.CompanyId = someCompanyId);
}

// Stuff happens here

var newEmployee = CreateNewEmployee();

using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    context.Companies.Attach(company);  // <<-- Extremely slow
    company.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

How would I go about detaching the employees list?

**Edit:  There will be no changes to the loaded employees (except for the new addition)**

Comment: Why do you need to attach the company to the context in this case? It shouldn't be necessary to do so for SaveChanges to work, AFAIK. Or is there something more to what you're doing with the second context?

Comment: How long does in take? How are you sure this is slow? Did you measure the time it takes? Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304009/entity-framework-attach-is-slow

Comment: Also are the entities proxy?

Comment: @Magnus: I need the company attached for other reasons, but thanks for making that clear.

Comment: Ok, so you need the company, but do you need all the associated employees to be attached as well? If not, can you not simply do `company.Employees.Clear()` (or `company.Employees = new List<Employee>()`) before attaching it? It's not very surprising that attaching thousands of employees to a context is taking a while.

Comment: @Alireza: Yes, I've been measuring it.  It takes a good couple of seconds on my dev environment. I'm not sure what proxy is... will read up.

Comment: @Magnus: But when saving changes, wouldn't it then delete those entities from the database?  Or does `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` prevent that?

Comment: I don't think so (though I'm not 100% sure), as long as you do the clear outside the context. I don't work much with navigation properties, so I'll have to defer to others at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off AutoDetectChanges

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I've tried this (questioned edited).  It still takes a couple of seconds to attach.