# EntityFramework is painfully slow at executing an update query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're investigating a performance issue where EF 6.1.3 is being painfully slow, and we cannot figure out what might be causing it.

The database context is initialized with:

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

We have isolated the performance issue to the following method:

```
protected virtual async Task<long> UpdateEntityInStoreAsync(T entity,
                                                            string[] changedProperties)
{
    using (var session = sessionFactory.CreateReadWriteSession(false, false))
    {
        var writer = session.Writer<T>();
        writer.Attach(entity);
        await writer.UpdatePropertyAsync(entity, changedProperties.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    return entity.Id;
}
```

There are two names in the changedProperties list, and EF correctly generated an update statement that updates just these two properties.

This method is called repeatedly (to process a collection of data items) and takes about 15-20 seconds to complete.

If we replace the method above with the following, execution time drops to 3-4 seconds:

```
protected virtual async Task<long> UpdateEntityInStoreAsync(T entity,
                                                            string[] changedProperties)
{
    var sql = $"update {entity.TypeName()}s set";
    var separator = false;
    foreach (var property in changedProperties)
    {
         sql += (separator ? ", " : " ") + property + " = @" + property;
         separator = true;
    }
    sql += " where id = @Id";
    var parameters = (from parameter in changedProperties.Concat(new[] { "Id" })
                      let property = entity.GetProperty(parameter)
                      select ContextManager.CreateSqlParameter(parameter, property.GetValue(entity))).ToArray();
    using (var session = sessionFactory.CreateReadWriteSession(false, false))
    {
        await session.UnderlyingDatabase.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    return entity.Id;
}
```

The UpdatePropertiesAsync method called on the writer (a repository implementation) looks like this:

```
public virtual async Task UpdatePropertyAsync(T entity, string[] changedPropertyNames, bool save = true)
{
    if (changedPropertyNames == null || changedPropertyNames.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Array.ForEach(changedPropertyNames, name => context.Entry(entity).Property(name).IsModified = true);
    if (save)
        await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

What is EF doing that completely kills performance? And is there anything we can do to work around it (short of using another ORM)?

Comment: Isnt there a SaveChangesAsync() you could try this

Comment: @selectDistinct Added code showing how the changes are applied to the context and subsequently saved using SaveChangesAsync.

Comment: Does your entity have a lot of references to other data objects that will also be implicitly Attached?  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304009/entity-framework-attach-is-slow) for an example of a large graph requiring 2.5 seconds for the Attach by itself.

Comment: @DanBryant My solution was similar - I manually set all references to null and restored them after the operation, which reduced time significantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By timing the code I was able to see that the additional time spent by EF was in the call to Attach the object to the context, and not in the actual query to update the database.

By eliminating all object references (setting them to `null` before attaching the object and restoring them after the update is complete) the EF code runs in "comparable times" (5 seconds, but with lots of logging code) to the hand-written solution.

So it looks like EF has a "bug" (some might call it a feature) causing it to inspect the attached object recursively even though change tracking and validation have been disabled.

Update: EF 7 appears to have addressed this issue by allowing you to pass in a GraphBehavior enum when calling Attach.

Comment: I feel your pain.  Attach was so slow in my application that I wound up creating a long-lived context for all of my frequently-updated objects so that I can flag Modified without having to Attach first.

Comment: So, how do we fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Entity framework is that when you call SaveChanges(), insert statements are sent to database one by one, that's how Entity works.

And actually there are 2 db hits per insert, first db hit is insert statement for a record, and the second one is select statement to get the id of inserted record.

So you have `numOfRecords * 2` database trips * time for one database trip.

Write this in your code `context.Database.Log = message => Debug.WriteLine(message);` to log generated sql to console, and you will see what am I talking about.

You can use BulkInsert, here is the link: https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

Comment: While it is correct what you write, it misses the point of the question: First, the query is an update query, so both methods send only one query per entity. Second, even if EF was doing something stupid query-wise (which it isn't according to the queries seen in SQL Profiler), it is still about a factor of 5 slower than the hand-written SQL doing the exact same thing. I'd expect some overhead going through an ORM, but not anywhere near what I'm seeing..

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as though you already have tried setting:

```
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

And you are not using an ordered lists, I think you are going to have to refactor your code and do some benchmarking.

I believe the bottleneck is coming from the `foreach` as the context is having to deal with a potentially large amounts of bulk data (not sure how many this is in your case).

Try and cut the items contained in your array down into smaller batches before calling the `SaveChanges();` or `SaveChangesAsync();` methods, and note the performance deviations as apposed to letting the context grow too large.

Also, if you are still not seeing further gains, try disposing of the context post `SaveChanges();` and then creating a new one, depending on the size of your entities list, flushing out the context may yield even further improvements.

But this all depends on how many entities we are talking about and may only be noticeable in the hundreds and thousands of record scenarios.

Comment: There is only one entity per call to SaveChangesAsync (the outer UpdateEntityInStore method is called per entity, and it creates the context, attaches the object, marks it as modified, saves changes, and disposes the context). I'm doing some Stopwatch measurements now, which indicate that the time sink is in fact the Attach method and not the call to SaveChanges. Unexpected but at least gives me some pointers.